# Why does KDE/plasma resize konsole fonts strangely when monitor size changes?

Tags: kde, fonts, konsole, plasma

I'm running KDE/plasma on Arch Linux in VirtualBox on a Mac laptop in full-screen mode.

When I connect the laptop to an external monitor, the desktop automatically resizes, as it should, and konsole windows change their size a bit.

At the same time, the konsole font gets messed up: the graphical rendering of the shell prompt, for example, seems to be of a different length than where konsole thinks the cursor is. As a result, an already-open konsole window becomes unreadable. Opening up a new konsole fixes the problem.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Versions: plasma 5.3.1, kde 5.11.0, konsole 15.04.2

**Added:** turns out that if I increase/decrease the font, everything resets to something readable.